# Как получить список таблиц с помощью курсора в psycopg2

Tags: python, база-данных, postgresql, psycopg2

Есть ли какой-то метод курсора в psycopg2 для решения данной задачи? Если нет то как это сделать или где почитать что бы понять как сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sql = "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public'"
cursor.execute(sql)
tables = cursor.fetchall()
```